# Android Honeycomb: How to style right corner arrow in spinner on an ActionBar

Tags: android, spinner, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

This is a pretty specific question. I have a spinner on an ActionBar that is added in the onCreate() method. I have been able to style the text white, but I can't get the underline and the triangle/arrow at the bottom right to appear as white. Here is my styling:

```
<item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/customActionBarDropDownStyle</item>

<style name="customActionBarDropDownStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

I can't find a style item/property that makes the underline and triangle white. Does one exists?

Here's an example. I have highlighted in red the triangle and underline that I want to make white.

[image]

Comment: No, I haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late answer, but better than never :)
You should create a new 9 patch drawable and set it as a background to android:actionDropDownStyle.

here is an example:

```
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/customActionBarDropDownStyle</item>
    <style name="customActionBarDropDownStyle"parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_spinner_dropdown</item>
    </style>
```

You can't set a color to almost every native component, as their backgrounds are (in most cases) 9-patch pngs.

Answer (score 1):

The actionDropDownStyle can not used to change the style of spinner you added on actionbar; its for one of the actionbar mode **ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST**;

As for your problem, you can define a selector for your spinner in the layout file,just like this:

```
enter code here
<Spinner
    android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_spinner"
    android:id="@+id/action_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_disabled" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_pressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_default" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `android:background="@null"`