# Android Spinner Action Bar removing underline

Tags: android-actionbar, android-spinner

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGxbu.png
Above is image of my action bar.

First question.
How do I remove that underline below text "Hot Picks" but keep bottomRight triangle?

Second.
How do I make topLeft icon not have padding?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem once; but I solved it now; You can see it here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/17854265/2618051